# Calculate the padding to center-align a rectangle (resized by percentage)

Tags: java, algorithm, swing

[image]

Below is my current algorithm to align the rectangle (representing symbol) in the center of the canvas space (representing icon). It is only the algorithm I am interested in so ignore the rest of the code as it is merely for demonstration purposes as a visual aid.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class IconSymbol extends JFrame {

    public IconSymbol(double iWH, double s, double w, double h) {

        getContentPane().add(new Canvas((int)iWH, s, w, h));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize((int)iWH, (int)iWH);
        setVisible(true);        
    }

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        IconSymbol is = new IconSymbol(100, 0.9, 50, 50);
    }

    class Canvas extends JPanel {

        // STIPULATED
        double iconWH = 0;
        double sScale = 0;
        double sWidth = 0;
        double sHeight = 0;

        // CALCULATED
        double padX = 0;
        double padY = 0;
        double xOffSet = 0;
        double yOffSet = 0;

        public Canvas(double iWH,double sS,double sW,double sH) {
            this.iconWH = iWH;
            this.sScale = sS;
            this.sWidth = sW;
            this.sHeight = sH;
        }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2D.setBackground(Color.WHITE);             

        g2D.setPaint(Color.BLUE);

        Shape icon = new Rectangle.Double(0,0,(int)iconWH,(int)iconWH);
        g2D.fill(icon);

        g2D.setPaint(Color.BLACK);

        int width = (int)iconWH / 10;
        int height= (int)iconWH / 10;
        for(int row=0;row<10;row++){
            for(int col=0;col<10;col++){
                g.drawRect(row*width,col*height,width,height);
            }
        }            

        Point off = algorithm(); 

        g2D.setPaint(Color.RED);            

        Shape s = new Rectangle.Double(off.x,off.y,(int)sWidth,(int)sHeight);

        AffineTransform tran = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(sScale, sScale);

        g2D.fill(tran.createTransformedShape(s));

    }

    public Point algorithm(){
        // ALGORITHM WITH EXACT NEEDED PARAMETERS
        padX = (sWidth - ((sWidth * sScale))) / 2;
        padY = (sHeight - ((sHeight * sScale))) / 2;
        xOffSet = padX + ((iconWH - (sWidth * sScale)) / 2);
        yOffSet = padX + ((iconWH - (sHeight * sScale)) / 2);            
        Point point = new Point((int)xOffSet, (int)yOffSet);
        return point;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post pictures of how the rectangle is looking so far ?

Comment: it's unclear what your variables represent.   what is `xoffset` vs `padX`, where the latter is unused?

Comment: Many one will get "nuts" when combining AffineTransform with own calculation; do either one. I would start without AffineTransform. You did a scaling on a rectangle with already calculated (x, y). As that is not the center but top-left, everything gets more complicated than it needs to be. So a shape with `sWidth*sScale`. And use less fields/variables.

Comment: Is your eventual goal to calculate the _padding dimensions_ or just to align the rectangle?

Comment: My intention is to only get the offset values. As I said the rest of the code is merely a visual aid. The algorithm to generate the correct offset is what I want.

Comment: I was intedning to add the padX and padY to handle the offset.

Comment: I attached the image with the 2 variations of the algorithm. So far much appreciated for the effort.

Comment: it's a whole mess of calculations that one has to be assigned one hour of reading - do you even understand these calculations?? - i dont know if the below answer did it for you you should then accept it

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that the scale transform `tran` is scaling the calculated origin of the rectangle, `off`, as well as `sWidth` and `sHeight`. If you want to keep with your current scheme you need to apply the inverse of the scale transform to the calculated offset in your `algorithm` method:

```
public Point algorithm(){
    // ALGORITHM WITH EXACT NEEDED PARAMETERS
    xOffSet = ((iconWH - (sWidth * sScale)) / 2) / sScale;
    yOffSet = ((iconWH - (sHeight * sScale)) / 2) / sScale; 
    Point point = new Point((int)xOffSet, (int)yOffSet);
    return point;
}
```

Note that I removed `padX` and `padY` as they weren't required for calculating the offset.